# React: How to pass in props from a <Link /> on React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working with Hacker News API and now I can link to my `Comments.js` with the ID of the story in the URL like this

```
export default function Story ({storyID}) {

const [story, setStory] = useState({});

 useEffect(()=> {

    getStoryTitle(storyID).then(data => data && data.url && setStory(data));
 });

    const kids = story.kids ? story.kids: [];
     const author = story.by;
        return (

          <div className="story-wrapper">

             <a className="a-tag" href={story.url}>
               <p className="story-title">{story.title}</p>
             </a>
             <p className="story-author"><strong>By: {story.by}</strong> on {timeFormat(story.time)}</p>
             <p className="story-comments"><Link to={`/comments/${storyID}`}>{kids.length}</Link> Comments</p>
             {
```

EDIT: I have my `Comments.js` like this

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {getStoryTitle} from '../API.js'
const {comment}
export default function Comments({storyID}) {
    const [comment, setComment] = useState({});


    useEffect(()=> {
        getStoryTitle(storyID).then(data => setComment(data))
    }, [])

    return (
        <ul>
            <li>{storyID}</li>
        </ul>
    )
}
```

I need to know how I can render the data in my `Comments.js` component similar to how I am doing with the story title and author using the prop that is passed in on the  url.

Comment: Are you asking how to access the route props passed from `Route`? Or are you trying to send some state with the route push from the `Link`? Something else?

Comment: No in the my Comments component I will create a state using a hook. I just need to send in some data to the component. I'm not sure if I am making sense

Comment: Well, you can send different types of data differently, depending on the scenario. The path itself, query parameters appended to the url, route state that is sent with the push. What are you trying to send? Please be as specific as possible as *data* is a really generic term.

Comment: Kind of similar to how I am using the storyIDs to display the title and author in my Story component I want to be able to do the same thing in my Comments component. I am trying to get the ID from the story and display the comments that are in the ID.

Comment: You can get that id from the `match` prop from the `Route` that renders the `Comments` component. How is `Comments` component being rendered?

Comment: I went ahead and updated my post to show the Comments.js

Comment: Still have no idea how `Comments` is being rendered, but updated answer with how to access the `storyID`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have it set up like this <Route exact path="/comments/:id" component={Comments}></Route> in my App.js

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with Hacker News API at all but do you know how I can access the id's for the parent comment? Right now I do something like <li>{[comment.parent]}</li> I don't receive anything back

Answer (score 3):

[match](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match)

Given the comments route path is defined as `path="/comments/:commentId"`, access the id from the `match` prop.

```
this.props.match.params.commentId
```

[location](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location)

If you need to send state with the route push, it is sent in the link's `to` prop as an object specifying the `pathname` and `state` to be sent to the new route.

```
to={{ pathname: `/comments/${storyID}`, state: { data } }}
```

Access from the `location` prop.

```
this.props.location.state.data
```

*data* can be anything valid as an object payload

**edit**

Assuming `Comments` is rendered as such:

```
<Route path="/comments/:id" component={Comments} />
```

Then unpack the `id` from the received `match` prop:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getStoryTitle } from '../API.js';

export default function Comments({ match }) {
  const { id } = match.params;
  const [comment, setComment] = useState({});

  useEffect(()=> {
    getStoryTitle(id).then(data => setComment(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      <li>{id}</li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: `/comments/${storyID}`,
  state: {
    yourData: 'fooBar'
  }
}}>{kids.length}</Link>
```

and inside your component you want to render the data:

```
const { yourData} = this.props.location.state
```